# Limit Foreignkey choices in form

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I have a form which has a foreignkey field 'mon_1', I am trying to limit it's choice by using **init** () method, but no changes is reflected in my webpage (Even if I make errors intentionally, it doesn't throw an error).

****Note****: 'limit_choices_techers' function works fine, no error in that piece of code

#forms.py

```
def limit_choices_teachers(period):
    limited_choice = []
    already_used_choice = TimeTable.objects.values_list(period,flat=True) #returns id of the teacher already linked on that period
    for teacher in Teachers.objects.all():
        if teacher.id not in already_used_choice:
            limited_choice.append(teacher)
    return limited_choice


class TimeTableForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = models.TimeTable
        fields = ('__all__')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TimeTableForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['mon_1'].queryset = limit_choices_teachers('mon_1')
```

#models.py

```
class Subjects(models.Model):
    Subjects_available = (
        ('Maths','Maths'),
        ('English','English'),
        ('Computer','Computer'),
        ('Chemistry','Chemistry'),
        ('Physics','Physics'),
    )
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length = 256,choices = Subjects_available,unique=True)

    def  __str__(self):
        return str(self.subject_name)

class Teachers(models.Model):
    classes_available = (
        ('Grade 1','Grade 1'),
        ('Grade 2','Grade 2'),
        ('Grade 3','Grade 3'),
        ('Grade 4','Grade 4'),
        ('Grade 5','Grade 5'),
        ('Grade 6','Grade 6'),
        ('Grade 7','Grade 7'),
        ('Grade 8','Grade 8'),
        ('Grade 9','Grade 9'),
        ('Grade 10','Grade 10'),
        ('Grade 11','Grade 11'),
        ('Grade 12','Grade 12'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subjects,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='teacher_subject')
    teaches_for_class = models.CharField(max_length=256,choices=classes_available)

    def  __str__(self):
        return str(self.subject) + ' - ' + self.name

class TimeTable(models.Model):
    standard_choice = (
        ('Grade 1','Grade 1'),
        ('Grade 2','Grade 2'),
        ('Grade 3','Grade 3'),
        ('Grade 4','Grade 4'),
        ('Grade 5','Grade 5'),
        ('Grade 6','Grade 6'),
        ('Grade 7','Grade 7'),
        ('Grade 8','Grade 8'),
        ('Grade 9','Grade 9'),
        ('Grade 10','Grade 10'),
        ('Grade 11','Grade 11'),
        ('Grade 12','Grade 12'),
    )

    section_choice = (
        ('A','A'),
        ('B','B'),
        ('C','C'),
        ('D','D'),
    )

    standard = models.CharField(max_length=256,choices=standard_choice)
    section = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=section_choice)

    mon_1 = models.ForeignKey(Teachers,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='mon_1_subject_teacher')
    mon_2 = models.ForeignKey(Teachers,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='mon_2_subject_teacher')
    mon_3 = models.ForeignKey(Teachers,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='mon_3_subject_teacher')
    mon_4 = models.ForeignKey(Teachers,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='mon_4_subject_teacher')
    mon_5 = models.ForeignKey(Teachers,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='mon_5_subject_teacher')

    tue_1 = models.ForeignKey(Teachers,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='tue_1_subject_teacher')
    tue_2 = models.ForeignKey(Teachers,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='tue_2_subject_teacher')
    tue_3 = models.ForeignKey(Teachers,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='tue_3_subject_teacher')
    tue_4 = models.ForeignKey(Teachers,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='tue_4_subject_teacher')
    tue_5 = models.ForeignKey(Teachers,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='tue_5_subject_teacher')

    wednes_1 = models.ForeignKey(Teachers,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='wed_1_subject_teacher')
    wednes_2 = models.ForeignKey(Teachers,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='wed_2_subject_teacher')
    wednes_3 = models.ForeignKey(Teachers,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='wed_3_subject_teacher')
    wednes_4 = models.ForeignKey(Teachers,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='wed_4_subject_teacher')
    wednes_5 = models.ForeignKey(Teachers,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='wed_5_subject_teacher')

    thurs_1 = models.ForeignKey(Teachers,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='thurs_1_subject_teacher')
    thurs_2 = models.ForeignKey(Teachers,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='thurs_2_subject_teacher')
    thurs_3 = models.ForeignKey(Teachers,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='thurs_3_subject_teacher')
    thurs_4 = models.ForeignKey(Teachers,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='thurs_4_subject_teacher')
    thurs_5 = models.ForeignKey(Teachers,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='thurs_5_subject_teacher')

    fri_1 = models.ForeignKey(Teachers,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='fri_1_subject_teacher')
    fri_2 = models.ForeignKey(Teachers,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='fri_2_subject_teacher')
    fri_3 = models.ForeignKey(Teachers,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='fri_3_subject_teacher')
    fri_4 = models.ForeignKey(Teachers,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='fri_4_subject_teacher')
    fri_5 = models.ForeignKey(Teachers,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='fri_5_subject_teacher')


    def  __str__(self):
        return self.standard+' '+self.section+ ' '+ 'TimeTable'

    # This works from one particular standard, but if some teachers take class for two grades , then you have 'ForeignKey'
    # the 'class they take' here and set unique_together constraint - hope it works
    class Meta():
        unique_together = [
        ['standard','section'],

        ['standard','mon_1'],
        ['standard','mon_2'],
        ['standard','mon_3'],
        ['standard','mon_4'],
        ['standard','mon_5'],

        ['standard','tue_1'],
        ['standard','tue_2'],
        ['standard','tue_3'],
        ['standard','tue_4'],
        ['standard','tue_5'],

        ['standard','wednes_1'],
        ['standard','wednes_2'],
        ['standard','wednes_3'],
        ['standard','wednes_4'],
        ['standard','wednes_5'],

        ['standard','thurs_1'],
        ['standard','thurs_2'],
        ['standard','thurs_3'],
        ['standard','thurs_4'],
        ['standard','thurs_5'],

        ['standard','fri_1'],
        ['standard','fri_2'],
        ['standard','fri_3'],
        ['standard','fri_4'],
        ['standard','fri_5'],
        ]
```

#views.py

```
class CreateTimeTable(CreateView):
    model = models.TimeTable
    form_class = forms.TimeTableForm
    template_name = 'TimeTableApp/create_time_table.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('TimeTableApp:inner_index')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A queryset is not a list, try to stick to queryset methods as much as possible.
You could try something like that:

```
def limit_choices_teachers(period):
    return Teacher.objects.exclude(id__in=TimeTable.objects.values_list(f"{period}_id",flat=True))


class TimeTableForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = models.TimeTable
        fields = ('__all__')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TimeTableForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['mon_1'].queryset = limit_choices_teachers('mon_1')
```